# Modx plugin resource return

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources, modx-plugins

I need to return to user whole resource in his own template via plugin, which handles on OnPageNotFound event. It can be diifferent pages, depends on link. I will parse it and get resource needed.
How can i do it?

Comment: Give us what you have for now

Answer (score 0):

All you need is https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/symlink/using-resource-symlinks

> You can add a new template or what ever changes you may want to the
>   symlink, and you can place it anywhere within the site.